# How to address "Can't decide which property to consider the Key" error

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

I'm getting this error message:

> "Can't decide which property to consider the Key - you can create one called 'ID' or mark one with SubSonicPrimaryKey attribute"

The code in question is generated by the `context.tt`:

```
    public SqlQuery Delete<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> column) where T:new()
    {
        LambdaExpression lamda = column;
        SqlQuery result = new Delete<T>(this.Provider);
        result = result.From<T>();
        result.Constraints=lamda.ParseConstraints().ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

In my DB the respective table actually has a primary key called `ID`. And I tried to insert the `SubSonicPrimaryKey` Attribute:

```
    uint _ID;
    [SubSonicPrimaryKey]
    public uint ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should post the stack trace of your exception.

This is just a wild guess but I suppose subsonic finds two possible primary keys, the one called ID and one with the `SubSonicPrimaryKey` attribute and does not check wether they are equal and since the count of the possible keys is not equal to 1 the exception is thrown.

You should try to remove the `SubSonicPrimaryKey` attribute of your class, since the Property is already called `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your issue is related to the uint value type. SubSonic has is problems handling unsigned value types.
Try using a int property instead for your primary key!